# How to generate random sequences of words with a predefined probability?

Tags: python, random, nltk

This is my code to generate random sequences of word based on my unigrams model. Can somebody show me how to get the probability of the word from my dictionary so I can generate the random word. Im just a beginner so I don't know too much about python.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk import ngrams
from nltk import FreqDist

Textfile = "TrainingSetLab2.txt"
Unigrams ={}

for line in open(Textfile):
    line = line.rstrip()
    tokens = word_tokenize(line)
    fdist = FreqDist(Unigrams)
    for word in tokens:     
        if word in Unigrams:
            Unigrams[word] = Unigrams[word]+1


        else:
            Unigrams[word] = 1

    for word in Unigrams:
         n = fdist.N()



for k,v in Unigrams.items():
    prob = (v/n)

    print(k,v,prob)
print("Total word: ", n)
#761
word = "put"
for index in range(8):
    word = prob[word].generate()
    print (word)
```

I got this when I ran it :

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: i got this : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object when i try to run it.

Comment: can you post the whole Error? Where does the TypeError occur?

Comment: This is the whole error.. im really appreciate it if you can help.. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\generate unigram.py", line 34, in <module>
    word = prob[word].generate()
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: you try to run the function `generate()`from the float number `prob`, (computed by v/n in the loop above) . That seems weird -- Where is that `generate()` function from/what does it do? Can you look it up in the docs?

Comment: I'm trying to use Shannon's method which is using the probability of the word to generate the next word after word "put" in my text file. is it wrong to write generate() function like that?.

Comment: are you trying to make a dictionary of words with `for k,v in Unigrams.items():
    prob = (v/n)`?

Comment: yes..before this i thought that i can get the probability of word by adding this coding : cfreq_sam = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(nltk.bigrams(words))
cprob_sam = nltk.ConditionalProbDist(cfreq_sam, nltk.MLEProbDist) , but its only working on Bigrams no Unigrams. that's why i use the formula (v/n) to get the probability of each word stored in Unigram dictonary.

Comment: actually the problem with the probability was solved, but starting from this coding word = "put"
for index in range(8):
    word = prob[word].generate()
    print (word) , i dont know how to write it so it can generate the next seven words.

Comment: yes but the problem is that you are not adding the value to the dictionary. that's why things fall apart afterwards. try `prob[k] = v/n` in your `for` loop to make word: frequency pairs. Note that you will have to initialize the dictionary first, like so `prob={}`.

Comment: it is like this?  for k,v in Unigrams.items():
    prob = {}
    prob[k] = (v/n)
    word = "put"
    for index in range(5):
        word = prob[word].generate()
        print (word)
        print(k,v,prob)  , or i put the coding the wrong place.

Comment: i got this error after i make the changes..  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\generate unigram.py", line 31, in <module>
    word = prob[word].generate()
KeyError: 'the'

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set up the dictionary

```
prob ={} #set up dictionary

for k,v in Unigrams.items():
    prob[k] = v/n #make the word the key, the value is v/n
```

Now if you get a `KeyError` for 'the', that's because you have not entered the word 'the' into the dictionary. Try printing out the dictionary, and use one of the words that's actually in there.

Or do:

```
for item in prob:
    word = item.generate()
    print (word)
```

You might want to go over a basic [Python tutorial](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/) first so you will be able to tackle these more advanced problems better.

Edited the  `for` loop. You need to clarify for me / yourself : what input  `generate()` takes. If it takes a string / word, the above works. But then your variable setup (word = X, word in for loop) does not really make sense to me.

Comment: i already setup the dictionary and change the coding i got this error:    word = prob[item].generate()
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'generate'   . thank you for your help.. really appreciate it..

Comment: see above for my comments

Comment: generate() takes probability from the words in the dictionary , and generate new sentence based on that probability.

Comment: This the question:  write a program that reads in n-grams extracted by the first program and uses them to generate sentences as random sequences of words constrained by the n-gram model. Remember the Shannon method we learnt in class? Both the sentences for unigram and the bigram model should be generated. The length of the generated text should be at least 5 words, : the first program is to calculate the probability of word and we already got it. I don't really understand the this question, can u explain it to me. tq

Comment: well in that case your program is fundamentally not doing that; you need to at least define generate; also if this is a hw assignment i'm not going to do it for uyou

Comment: well,it is an assignment. and i'm stuck on this question for more than a month and i have tried so many ways. my lecturer extend the date of submission for me.That is why i really needs help. Btw, thanks for ur help :) .

Comment: yan, in that case you should ask a specific question (maybe in bullet points) not just "please fix it"; post all the code you have so far to show you have done your work and the whole error message. some of your errors seem very basic (e.g. I don't see how that "generate" thing is supposed to work). If you do that I'd be happy to help, but at this point there is just not a lot to work with. Also, is there no TA or other support for this class?